# keycloak pushing claims to the admin console

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

How to push claims in spring boot application?

policy:

```
var context = $evaluation.context;

var attributes = context.attributes;

if (attributes.containsValue('some-claim', 'claim-value')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

How to pass this claim in application.properties file?

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].claimInformationPointConfig.claims[some-claim]={request.parameter['parameter-a']}
```

In application.properties,it throws an error on passing claims.